# Jquery select SVG elements inside an <object> tag

Tags: jquery, html, object, svg

I have a SVG which has some linearGradient elements which changes at button click Everything works fine as you can [see here](https://jsfiddle.net/ionut1234/8pgf3s6j/5/).
My question is how could do the same thing if the svg from my example is an external file and is called in an `<object>` tag?

My SVG:

```
<object data="Img/PumpStation/Pump.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="alphasvg1111"></object>
```

My button:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" class="test" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

My jQuery function:

```
jQuery('.test').on('click', function () {
    //$("object").contents().find("path").attr({ "fill": "red" });
    jQuery('object stop').each(function () {
        var color = jQuery(this).css('stop-color');
        if (color === 'rgb(77, 77, 77)') {
            jQuery(this).css('stop-color', '#ff0000');
        }
    });
});
```

If I use: `$("object").contents().find("path").attr({ "fill": "red" });`, my SVG turns red when button is clicked. Why the rest of the function is not working?

Comment: What are you expecting “object stop” to select?

Comment: Search for all <stop> tags in the whole SVG.

Comment: The object tag you show doesn’t contain any stop tags though...

Comment: Ah I see from Peter’s answer what you are doing :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the contents of the object element:

```
jQuery('.test').on('click', function () {
    $("object").contents().find('stop').each(function () {
        var color = jQuery(this).css('stop-color');
        if (color === 'rgb(77, 77, 77)') {
            jQuery(this).css('stop-color', '#ff0000');
        }
    });
});
```